# When i try to build app using ng build --prod it says "Property 'invited_by' does not exist on type 'any[]' "

Tags: javascript, angular

What i am trying to do is, i have a button in my site it need's to show if the condition is true. It works on the local but show's error when i try to build.

```
<html>

<button
*ngIf="userType && userType == 'client' && experienceDetail.type != 'published' && userList.invited_by =='' " type="button" (click)='shareExp()' class="cus-btn">Share</button>
```

component.ts file

```
  invited_by: any=[]

ngOnInit() {

    
    this.getUserData();
  }


getUserData() {
    this.dataService.getUserData().subscribe((data) => {


      this.userList = data ? data : [];

      console.log(this.userList, 'f');

    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have an error in this `userList.invited_by` code in your `html`.
You try to get access to element `invited_by` of `userList` but `userList` is an array.

And when you try to build your app you get this error.

You should to iterate `userList` and you get access to the `invited_by` of each element :)

I hope It'll help you! Be happy and Have a clean code :)

Comment: I get userList data as object.
 `{_id: "5d53e24754846f46e51dd2bc", updatedAt: "2021-01-12T12:21:31.020Z", createdAt: "2019-08-14T10:28:23.180Z", first_name: "test", last_name: "user", …}
invited_by: "5ffd944a7178242e81e90e0c"`
i get data like this. How can i solve this issue.

Comment: Sorry, but why you do this `this.userList = data ? data : [];` if `this.userList` is an Object?

Comment: Could you `console.log(this.userList)` and show me?

Comment: Yes 1 sec buddy

Comment: `{_id: "5d53e24754846f46e51dd2bc", updatedAt: "2021-01-12T12:21:31.020Z", createdAt: "2019-08-14T10:28:23.180Z", first_name: "test", last_name: "user", …}
email: "test@gmail.com"
first_name: "test"
invited_by: "5ffd944a7178242e81e90e0c"
last_name: "user"
password: "8d969eef6ecad3c29a3a629280e686cf0c3f5d5a86aff3ca12020c923adc6c92"
password_uuid: "9f790a10-be7d-11e9-8e0c-7785d1a3f50a"
phone_number: ""
status: "active"
updatedAt: "2021-01-12T12:21:31.020Z"
user_type: "client"
__v: 0
_id: "5d53e24754846f46e51dd2bc"`

This is what i get in the console

Comment: try to do `this.userList: any = data ? data : []`

Comment: You have this problem because typeof `this.userList` now is `Object | any[]` I think :)

Comment: If `this.userList` is an Object, you have to do like this `this.userList = data ? data : {}`

Comment: Or just add real type to your `userList` like this

`interface IUserList {
  id: string;
  ....
}

this.userList: IUserList  = data;
`

Comment: Still error not solved :(. But when i add `interface Array<T> {
    invited_by: any[];` this in *lib.es5.d.ts* file it works. But the pblm is i can't save that file.

Comment: Nope buddy. I have been trying to solve this since last two days. But nothing worked out :(

Comment: is there any way that you can help me?

Comment: Yes, I can if you show me your code on github for example and I can create PR for you)

Comment: Have you tried this point `this.userList: any = data;`?

Comment: I added the ts and html file in github

Comment: https://github.com/dineshjbk/angular

this is the repository

Comment: whn is try `this.userList :any = data:` *it shows any refers to type but used as value*

Comment: https://github.com/RayZik/angular/commit/b45a89008774de50bc5cbbc509465d7c750b407a

I hope this commit will help you)

Comment: I don't get what ur trying to say. can u pls eloborate the issue and what i need to do here.
thanks in advance

Comment: I tried to say you what error is. But we can't understand each other. I can fix this error if you give me temporary access to you project or we can use https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/services/live-share/ live share extension and I will fix it)

Comment: I changed  `userList:<array>any=[]`  `userList: any;` now it works :)))))))
Thank you so much @Aleksey . I like to be in touch with you buddy

Comment: 
But your code isn't clear, my advice - try to clean your code. `any` is a bad practice!
So I'm happy that I could help you!

Comment: And Please, mark your question as resolved. Thanks)

Comment: [link](https://join.skype.com/invite/WEwz3PcHeWxD) 
this is my skype link send me a txt or drop ur id i will txt you. BTW thanks again buddy

Comment: No problem) I sent you message)

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved pls go through the comments to understand what causes the issue. Refer https://github.com/RayZik/angular/commit/b45a89008774de50bc5cbbc509465d7c750b407a
this commit. You will understand clearly.